# Reference figure via asterisk in Latex Beamer

Tags: beamer

Good morning,

Instead of referencing a figure using the command *footnote* in a caption, I'd like my figure to have no caption in order to save space. Instead, the figure shall be referenced by an asterisk at the bottom right corner of the figure like in the attached example and the reference shall appear at the frame's footline. How can this be brought about most easily, i.e. without manually placing the asterisk according to some coordinates by trial and error until its in the right position?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?
Taken from [beautiful LaTeX eBooK in examples](https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{(\fnsymbol{footnote})}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}\footnote[1]{image description}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Also**

Just by changing the value of the number you can insert the symbol of your choice.

1. asterisk *
2. dagger †
3. double dagger ‡
4. section symbol §
5. paragraph ¶
6. parallel lines ‖
7. two asterisks **
8. two daggers ††
9. two double daggers ‡‡

***Numbering case***
I do not know how to do it properly, hence it will be  very manual and hardcoding:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\customfootnotetext}[2]{{% Group to localize change to footnote
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{#1}% Update footnote counter representation
\footnotetext[0]{#2}}}% Print footnote text


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image} (1)\customfootnotetext{(1)}{Some text}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beamer doesn't have a floating mechanism, so you don't need `[h]`. Beamer automatically centres the content of the figure environment, `\center` is 1) wrong syntax (because it is an environment) and 2) not needed.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 
oh, thank you for explanation, I didn't know that

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Thank you very much, the code example works fine! Is it somehow possible to leave a bit more horizontal space between the figure and the asterisk? Is it furthermore possible to also use numbers instead of an asterisk, because on some of my slides due to a lot of necessary references a numbering would be more suitable?

Comment: @user278966 "more horizontal space" use: ```\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{ (\fnsymbol{footnote})}```
For everything else see my edits above, also see my full book in with examples here https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook (example 6.5) if I helped You star the project, I would appreciate it very much